# Convert PDF to TIFF using ImageMagick & C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I have an existing program that does some processing a .pdf file and splitting it into multiple .pdf files based on looking for barcodes on the pages.

The program uses ImageMagick and C#.

I want to change it from outputting pdfs to outputting tifs.  Look for the comment in the code below for where I would guess the change would be made.

I included the ImageMagick tag because someone might offer a commandline option that someone else can help me convert to C#.

```
private void BurstPdf(string bigPdfName, string targetfolder)
{
    bool outputPdf = true;  // change to false to output tif.
    string outputExtension = "";

    var settings = new MagickReadSettings { Density = new Density(200) };

    string barcodePng = Path.Combine("C:\TEMP", "tmp.png");

    using (MagickImageCollection pdfPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
    {
        pdfPageCollection.Read(bigPdfName, settings);

        int inputPageCount = 0;
        int outputPageCount = 0;
        int outputFileCount = 0;
        MagickImageCollection resultCollection = new MagickImageCollection();
        string barcode = "";
        string resultName = "";
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
        reader.Options.TryHarder = false;

        foreach (MagickImage pdfPage in pdfPageCollection)
        {
            MagickGeometry barcodeArea = getBarCodeArea(pdfPage);
            IMagickImage barcodeImg = pdfPage.Clone();

            barcodeImg.ColorType = ColorType.Bilevel;
            barcodeImg.Depth = 1;
            barcodeImg.Alpha(AlphaOption.Off);

            barcodeImg.Crop(barcodeArea);
            barcodeImg.Write(barcodePng);

            inputPageCount++;
            using (var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(barcodePng))
            {
                var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    // found a first page because it has bar code.
                    if (result.BarcodeFormat.ToString() == "CODE_39")
                    {

                        if (outputFileCount != 0)
                        {
                            // write out previous pages.
                            if (outputPdf) {
                                outputExtension = ".pdf";
                            } else {
                                // What do I put here to output a g4 compressed tif?
                                outputExtension = ".tif";
                            }
                            resultName = string.Format("{0:D4}", outputFileCount) + "-" + outputPageCount.ToString() + "-" + barcode + outputExtension;
                            resultCollection.Write(Path.Combine(targetfolder, resultName));
                            resultCollection = new MagickImageCollection();
                        }
                        barcode = standardizePhysicalBarCode(result.Text);

                        outputFileCount++;
                        resultCollection.Add(pdfPage);
                        outputPageCount = 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("WARNING barcode is not of type CODE_39 so something is wrong. check page " + inputPageCount + " of " + bigPdfName);
                        if (inputPageCount == 1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("barcode not found on page 1.  see " + barcodePng);
                        }
                        resultCollection.Add(pdfPage);
                        outputPageCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (inputPageCount == 1)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("barcode not found on page 1.  see " + barcodePng);
                    }
                    resultCollection.Add(pdfPage);
                    outputPageCount++;
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(barcodePng))
            {
                File.Delete(barcodePng);
            }

        }

        if (resultCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            if (outputPdf) {
                outputExtension = ".pdf";
            } else {
                // What do I put here to output a g4 compressed tif?
                outputExtension = ".tif";
            }
            resultName = string.Format("{0:D4}", outputFileCount) + "-" + outputPageCount.ToString() + "-" + barcode + outputExtension;
            resultCollection.Write(Path.Combine(targetfolder, resultName));
            outputFileCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]  The above code is what I am using (which some untested modifications) to split a .pdf into other .pdfs.  I want to know how to modify this code to output tiffs.  I put a comment in the code where I think the change would go.

[EDIT] So encouraged by @fmw42 I just ran the code with the .tif extension enabled.  Looks like it did convert to a .tif, but the tif is not compressed.  I am surprised that IM just configures the output based on the extension name of the file.  Handy I guess, but just seems a little loose.

[EDIT] I figured it out.  Although counter-intuitive ones sets the compression on the read of the file.  I am reading a .pdf but I set the compression to Group for like this:

```
var settings = new MagickReadSettings { Density = new Density(200), Compression = CompressionMethod.Group4 };
```

The thing I learned was that simply naming the output file .tif tells IM to output a tif.  That is a handy way to do it, but it just seems sloppy.

Comment: Have you tried your code? Were there errors? It looks reasonable to me, but I do not code in C or C++. In command line, you do not need to loop. You could use: `convert image.pdf +adjoin image.tiff`. That would create image-0.tiff, image-1.tiff ... automatically adding the page number. You can also use -scene 1 if you want to start the numbering at 1 rather than 0. The same command goes if you output to pdf. The +adjoin forces ImageMagick to avoid creating a multi-page file.

Comment: This code works (with the caveat that I made some simplifications for SO).  But it outputs a .pdf.  I want it to output a g4 tiff.

Comment: Does your if test switch for tiff not work? For group 4, you will need to set the compression to group4, before the output. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress. Sorry, I do not know C#. Suggest you ask at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27